# Data sampling technique and questions

Tags: machine-learning, distribution, sample, sampling

I'm just a little confused about data sampling, what distribution should I expect for my sampling data? In general, do I want my sampling data has the same distribution as my whole dataset? I wonder what is a reasonable sampling technique and approach?

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Could you give some more specifics about your problem?  Maybe tell us what you tried and why it didn't work as you expected. 
 Otherwise it may be closed as 'overly-broad'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors to consider in choosing a sampling technique. Factors such as the purpose or objective of work, your budget, time and even sample size are worth considering when choosing a sampling technique.

Probability Sampling techniques are usually more involving while Non-Probability Sampling techniques may be less demanding.

The sampling technique chosen goes a long way affecting the interpretation of the data, as well as the overall outcome of your work.
These notes may be of interest:

[Simple Random Sampling and Other Sampling Methods](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat100/node/18/)

Comment: This is far too broad to be answered here. And it's not a programming question. Best not to answer such subjective, open-ended questions (plus this is more of an opinion and general thoughts, vs an objective answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question well, but I will try to answer.
Student's ‘t’ Distribution is essentially a normal distribution (with an approximate shape of a bell), that is why the statistical programs often have in them the statistical expressions of the Student 't' distribution instead of the normal distribution.

Comment: Remember that this answer  an exemple.

Comment: Hi @Ricardo-Jose, thank you for contributing to stack overflow, but this question is not suitable for this forum (it has nothing to do with programming; it belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com/) so it will very likely be closed and your efforts will not be appreciated. Please continue to answer questions on this site, but please make sure they are appropriate and, ideally, ['good'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions